# SVN asking for password after checking out a fresh copy of the repository

Tags: svn, debian

I've had a small issue with pushing to the repository with Tortoise SVN and after messing around with the repository in my frenzy I managed to delete the `.svn/entries` file and after that all hell broke loose. I though by just checking-out the project again would solve the problem, but now it asks for the password every time we try to do a `svn up`:

```
Authentication realm: <http://some.ip.address:80> Subversion Repository
Password for 'this-user':
```

After the password is entered I see the infamous prompt:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ATTENTION!  Your password for authentication realm:

   <http://some.ip.address:80> Subversion Repository

can only be stored to disk unencrypted!  You are advised to configure
your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if
possible.  See the documentation for details.

You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value
of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in
'/home/this-user/.subversion/servers'.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Store password unencrypted (yes/no)?
```

It doesn't matter if I choose yes or no. I haven't changed anything in the `~/.subversion/servers` file The `store-passwords = no` and `store-plaintext-passwords = no` are commented out.

What puzzles me is that for another repository we don't have this issue while for this newly checked out version we're always prompted. So the setting must be somewhere in the checkout repository, but I have no idea what it is. I'm looking for a solution that will preferably apply to all users, not just me.

- SVN client version: 1.6.12 (`svn --version`)
- SVN server version: 1.6.12 (`svnserve --version`)

**Update**: If another colleges checks out the project everything works fine, no password requested for updates. But if I checkout the repository then we all have to enter our passwords for updates. Maybe a difference in SVN users permissions?

Any pointers or suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check your `$HOME/.subversion/config` file. Especially `store-auth-creds`. Also make sure your `$HOME/.subversion/config` is writable to you as a user.

Comment: I already looked in there and it's writable: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 my-user www-data 6.8K Jun 17 17:51 config`

Comment: And `# store-auth-creds = no` is commented out. I didn't change anything in the config files. The weird part with these settings I don't have any problem with another repository.

Comment: I looked at another colleague's `$HOME/.subversion/config` file and he also has the default version just like me. But if he checks out the project we don't have to add the password. I'm starting to think the difference is in the linux users or something...